# Сравнение DateTime через LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Стыдно, знаю. Не нагуглил. Как вывести всех людей, у которых ДР меньше чем в переменной defaultDateTimes? Через LINQ

```
public class Person1
{
    public string Name;
    public DateTime Birthday;
}

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    DateTime defaultDateTimes = new DateTime(2000,1,1);

    var people = new List<Person1>();
    var p1 = new Person1() { Name = "Leslie", Birthday = new DateTime(1983, 9, 4) };
    var p2 = new Person1() { Name = "Chris", Birthday = new DateTime(2001, 6, 19) };
    var p3 = new Person1() { Name = "JP", Birthday = new DateTime(1983, 4, 5) };
  }
}
```

Comment: О, у вас теперь правильный класс `Person`, ура!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например, так:

```
DateTime defaultDateTimes = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);

var people = new List<Person1>()
{
    new Person1() { Name = "Leslie", Birthday = new DateTime(1983, 9, 4) },
    new Person1() { Name = "Chris", Birthday = new DateTime(2001, 6, 19) },
    new Person1() { Name = "JP", Birthday = new DateTime(1983, 4, 5) }
};

var filteredPeople = people.Where(p => p.Birthday < defaultDateTimes);
foreach (var p in filteredPeople)
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
```

---

LINQ предназначено для преобразования данных. Оно умеет, например, отбирать данные из списка (как в вашем случае людей) и преобразовывать их. Выполнять действия с данными (например, вывести имя человека) LINQ не умеет (да и не предназначено для этого).

Поэтому в вашей задаче фильтрация данных — дело LINQ, а для вывода нужно использовать обыкновенный цикл `foreach`.

Comment: Спасибо большое :)

Comment: @NameJ: Пожалуйста!